# How do I delay a function call for 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `widget.Rotator.rotate()` to be delayed 5 seconds between calls... how do I do this in jQuery... it seems like jQuery's `delay()` wouldn't work for this...

Comment: Do you want it to automatically be called with a delay of 5 seconds between invocations, or will this be called in response to a user action and you want to ensure that it waits at least 5 seconds after the last invocation before going again? If the latter, should the user be able to queue up events, or should the input be ignored if 5 seconds have not elapsed?

Comment: I understand that this is a duplicate, but 5 times more people land on this question because of the way the title is composed. Many of us are searching for the keyword _delay_ and not _sleep_.
And the answer is more general too. So, in this case, this question is more relevant than the other, in my opinion.

Answer (score 588, accepted):

You can use plain javascript, this will call your_func once, after 5 seconds:

```
setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 5000);
```

If your function has no parameters and no explicit receiver you can call directly `setTimeout(func, 5000)`

There is also a plugin I've used once. It has `oneTime` and `everyTime` methods.

- [jQuery timers plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timer/)

Comment: If there are no function parameters, there is no need to wrap in a `function` - this will do fine: `setTimeout(your_func, 5000);`

Comment: @Oded Are you sure that `Rotator.rotate()` does not need the receiver to be set to `Rotator`? If you perfom what you suggest, `this` will be the window.

Comment: @Phrogz - I was talking about the mechanics of `setTimout`.

Comment: I suggest you modify your answer to say _"If your function has no parameters and no explicit receiver"_, or something similar but worded in a manner more clear to new programmers.

Comment: Also, you can use clearTimeout(myTimer) to stop the function from being called, if you use myTimer=setTimeout(...) when first calling setTimeout.

Comment: A better way to use  setTimeout(()=> { your_func() }, 5000);

Answer (score 34):

```
var rotator = function(){
  widget.Rotator.rotate();
  setTimeout(rotator,5000);
};
rotator();
```

Or:

```
setInterval(
  function(){ widget.Rotator.rotate() },
  5000
);
```

Or:

```
setInterval(
  widget.Rotator.rotate.bind(widget.Rotator),
  5000
);
```

Comment: setTimeout not block main thread ?