# JS remove and add class timing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is some js that i have no idea how to modify to do what i want. Instead of onclick i need the js to activate after a delay of 40 seconds.

```
// retrieve the element
element = document.getElementById("ani");

// reset the transition by...
element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault;

// -> removing the class
element.classList.remove("delay-1");

// -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
// without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be         retriggered.
element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

// -> and re-adding the class
element.classList.add("delay-1");
}, false);
```

Comment: Just use a [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to invoke a method/task after a specified number of milliseconds.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //your code/function here
}, (40*1000)); //40 seconds
```

Comment: Do i remove: "element.addEventListener("click", function(e){" I have almost 0 js knowledge

Comment: Yes. And the `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Got it working thanks alot! +1, final question can i get it to repeat every 40 seconds? I have multiple divs also do do this on but with same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function setTimeout.

as seen in e.g. [How do I delay a function call for 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738595/how-do-i-delay-a-function-call-for-5-seconds)

In your case:

```
// retrieve the element
element = document.getElementById("ani");

// reset the transition by...
element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault;

  //introducing a delay of 40 seconds.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // -> removing the class
    element.classList.remove("delay-1");

    // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
    // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be         retriggered.
    element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

    // -> and re-adding the class
    element.classList.add("delay-1");
  }, 40 * 1000);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // retrieve the element
    element = document.getElementById("ani");

    // reset the transition by...
    element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault;

    // -> removing the class
    element.classList.remove("delay-1");

    // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
    // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
    element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

    // -> and re-adding the class
    element.classList.add("delay-1");
    }, false);
}, 40000);
```