# How to disable a link (preventDefault()) for 10 seconds, after user clicks on it?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I want to disable a link for 10 seconds.
If would do permanently I would use that approach when user click on it:

```
if ($('#report-download').hasClass("disabled")) {
   e.preventDefault();
}
$('#report-download').addClass("disabled");
```

How could I revert that after 10 seconds?

```
setTimeout(function(){ revertPreventDefalt(){
// This is my question
}; }, 10000);
```

Note: the setTimeout is not the point. The point here is how to revert the preventDefault().

Comment: `setTimeout`? --

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738595/how-do-i-delay-a-function-call-for-5-seconds

Comment: just use a throttle function with a 10 second delay on it, see https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf

Comment: Note: the setTimeout is not the point. The point here is how to revert the preventDefault().