# How to have an img appear after time when page is loaded and disappear after time?

Tags: javascript, css

Dumb or basic question but i'm learning HTML/CSS/JS and i'm missing the JS part.

I need some help making an img appear after the page is loaded with (let's say) a 3 seconds delay, remain visible for 4 seconds and disappear. Probably only possible with JS and "i don't even basic" in JS.

Managed to get it to hide after 4 seconds but it's needed to delay it first

```
<div>
<img src="images/browsetip.png" class="browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>



<script>
  function doHide(){
    document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "none" ;
}
  function hideImage(){
    setTimeout( "doHide()", 4000 ) ;
}
</script>
```

[Image for more coherency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hj95.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help you.At the initial stage you can hide the image by using cssand after all dom content loaded you can show the image after 3 seconds.Then just after showing the image you can hide it after a 4 seconds delay.

```
<style>
    .browse-tip{
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
<div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hj95.png" class="browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>



<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      showImage();
      setInterval(hideImage, 4000);
    },3000);
  });
  function hideImage(){
    document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "none" ;
  }
  function showImage(){
    document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "block" ;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This works splendidly well! Thank you! *insert surprised pikachu here*

Answer (score 0):

Use window.onload. This will not fire until the contents of the page is loaded.

```
<div>
<img src="images/browsetip.png" class="browse-tip" id="imgHideShow">
</div>



<script>
window.onload = function() {
  function doHide(){
    document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "none" ;
  }
  function hideImage(){
    setTimeout( "doHide()", 4000 ) ;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at something like this, which is executed when your page loads:

```
(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "none" ;
   }, 4000);

})();
```

If JQuery is available, use this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById( "imgHideShow" ).style.display = "none" ;
   }, 4000);
});
```

You may want to look here for setting a timer on when to call the function:
[How do I delay a function call for 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738595/how-do-i-delay-a-function-call-for-5-seconds)

It's essentially the same thing you're doing when you wait 4 seconds before hiding the image.

Also, here's a better description of calling functions based on window.onload and document.onload: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="future-image"></div>

<script>
(function() {

   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.setAttribute('src','images/brosetip.png');
   img.setAttribute('id','imgHideShow');
   img.setAttribute('class','browse-tip');

   setTimeout( function(){
        var div = document.getElementById('future-image');
        div.insertBefore(img, div.firstChild);
        removeImg(div);
   },4000);

   var removeImg = function(div){
        setTimeout( function(){
            div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
        },4000);
   }

})();
</script>
```