# Delay a Function Using JQuery without settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner to coding and I've been trying to delay a button click function using timeout but it seems like not working.

To clarify it further, this button is supposed to do something, but when I add timeout function all it does is just delay it and not processing to the next line. Even with JavaScript is okay. Can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 setTimeout(function(){
 $("#mybutton").click(myButtonClicked);
 }, 1000);
 getURLParameter("run") && $("#mybutton").click()
});


function getURLParameter(a) {
 a = (new RegExp("[?|&]" + a + "=([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)")).exec(location.search);
 if (null == a) return null;
 a = a[1];
 a = a.replace(/\+/g, "%20");
 return decodeURIComponent(a)
}

function myButtonClicked() {
 disableMyButton();
 var a = $(".new").toArray(),
  c = $(".status").toArray();
 a.reverse();
 c.reverse();
 doNextBox(a, c)
}
```

What I'm trying to do is

1. Click button
2. Wait a second
3. Proceed to the next task

Comment: Where is your code of delay ?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated it now.

Comment: @RashmiNimesha we'll need acreate a **[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** to help you. However, you can check `.delay()` method on the **[jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)**

Comment: You need to wrap the other line in the `setTimeout`. `$("#mybutton").click(myButtonClicked);` installs the event listener (which you can and should do immediately), `$("#mybutton").click()` fires the click (which you want to do later, in the timeout callback).

Comment: Your code basically adds listener to click event after 1s, but you click it immediately. To make it work, you should switch .click methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delay a function call for 5 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738595/how-do-i-delay-a-function-call-for-5-seconds)

Comment: It's not. I've already tried it. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `setTimeout` in your 'click'-eventhandler, pass a function and the time after that this function should be executed...

Example:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
   setTimeout(doAfterTimeout, 1000);
});

function doAfterTimeout() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my issue. Now I see what I was doing wrong.